# Can I put a discrete GPU in my laptop?

Tags: gpu, computer-building, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision 7740 which shipped with no discrete graphics. Although the motherboard supports inserting a discrete GPU, the installation guide says that [it has no GPU power cable](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/precision-17-7740-laptop/precision_7740_service%20manual/installing-the-graphics-card?guid=guid-ca9dbc2c-c0ca-4d71-83df-db17ce4b64cd). If I want a GPU, am I stuck with getting an eGPU?

Answer (score 3):

No. Not for your model.  Confirm with the Note in section 2. Without the power cable, you cannot do the upgrade.

> NOTE: The above procedures are for UMA graphics card. Systems shipped
>   with UMA GPU card do not have GPU power cable. However, for discrete
>   models shipped with either a 128 MB or 256 MB VRAM GPU card, you need
>   to connect the GPU power cable after installing the GPU card.